# AngularJS code in Angular context: ng-if On a DIV, unexpected outcome

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

@angular/upgrade/static

I am trying to upgrade an AngularJS controller to Angular context using UpgradeModule from '@angular/upgrade/static'

When I change ng-show to ng-if on span or div the enclosed content does not display as expected
Using the stackbliz code is easier to see the issue,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcqzsy

Angular CLI: 7.0.6
Node: 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4
npm: 5.6.0

I am trying to use use AngularJS component in Angular application, and in the issue in this markup is, the contained span block with ng-repeat does not display, If I change the ng-if on the parent div to ng-show then the inner markup appears as expected

```
<div ng-if="vm.showMe == 'SHOW_ME'">
  <span ng-repeat="col in vm.colCollection">
    <h4 title="{{col.appName}}">Testing: {{col.appName}}</h4>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-show` is equivalent to `[hidden]` just does the opposite. means in both cases you have elements available and hidden in DOM. ngIf takes out the element from DOM. also it is `*ngIf` in angular7 world

Answer (score 0):

This will working same as ng-show.

```
<span ng-if="vm.allowed" ng-repeat="col in vm.colCollection">
    <h4 title="{{col.appName}}">Testing: {{col.appName}}</h4>
</span>
```